# Hibernate update OneToMany

Tags: mysql, hibernate, one-to-many

In Hibernate, I have two entity classes.

class A and class B.

class A contains a list of class B.

```
    @Entity
    class A{
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        List<B> list; // ArrayList
    }

    @Entity
    class B{
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
    }
```

Three tables will be created like this, table A, A_B, and B. Where A contains whatever entity A has, and A_B is the relation table, and B is whatever B is. I am saving/updating them by creating a new session, beginTransaction, saveOrUpdate, commit, and close the session.

Now, the problem is, whenever I add a new item to list and updates A, hibernate deletes the entire A_B table, and then inserts everything back with the new item. I actually just want it to add 1 new row to A_B and 1 new row to B.

---

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
```

The rest is pretty much standard

Comment: post your hibernate configuration(hibernate.cfg.xml) file here.

Comment: I should note that the object A is not persistent because I closed the session and there are no second level cache.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your hibernate configuration file, because you can provide configuration to delete previous table and create new table each time when server gets restarted.

Comment: I have made my update, I don't think that's the problem though.